# asp.net dropdownlist not updated from newly created html drop down

Tags: html, asp.net

I would like change asp dropdown default to rich look UI design by using css and javascript. After change the design original drop down list not selected. Here is the js script. the given script  not update original asp.net drown selected value.

```
<script>

    var x, i, j, selElmnt, a, b, c;
    /*look for any elements with the class "custom-select":*/
    x = document.getElementsByClassName("custom-select");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      selElmnt = x[i].getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
      /*for each element, create a new DIV that will act as the selected item:*/
      a = document.createElement("DIV");
      a.setAttribute("class", "select-selected");
      a.innerHTML = selElmnt.options[selElmnt.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
      x[i].appendChild(a);
      /*for each element, create a new DIV that will contain the option list:*/
      b = document.createElement("DIV");
      b.setAttribute("class", "select-items select-hide");
      for (j = 1; j < selElmnt.length; j++) {
        /*for each option in the original select element,
        create a new DIV that will act as an option item:*/
        c = document.createElement("DIV");
        c.innerHTML = selElmnt.options[j].innerHTML;
        c.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
            /*when an item is clicked, update the original select box,
            and the selected item:*/
            var y, i, k, s, h;
            s = this.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
            h = this.parentNode.previousSibling;
            for (i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
              if (s.options[i].innerHTML == this.innerHTML) {
                s.selectedIndex = i;
                h.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
                y = this.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("same-as-selected");
                for (k = 0; k < y.length; k++) {
                  y[k].removeAttribute("class");
                }
                this.setAttribute("class", "same-as-selected");
                break;
              }
            }
            h.click();
        });
        b.appendChild(c);
      }
      x[i].appendChild(b);
      a.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
          /*when the select box is clicked, close any other select boxes,
          and open/close the current select box:*/
          e.stopPropagation();
          closeAllSelect(this);
          this.nextSibling.classList.toggle("select-hide");
          this.classList.toggle("select-arrow-active");
        });
    }
    function closeAllSelect(elmnt) {
      /*a function that will close all select boxes in the document,
      except the current select box:*/
      var x, y, i, arrNo = [];
      x = document.getElementsByClassName("select-items");
      y = document.getElementsByClassName("select-selected");
      for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
        if (elmnt == y[i]) {
          arrNo.push(i)
        } else {
          y[i].classList.remove("select-arrow-active");
        }
      }
      for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        if (arrNo.indexOf(i)) {
          x[i].classList.add("select-hide");
        }
      }
    }
    /*if the user clicks anywhere outside the select box,
    then close all select boxes:*/
    document.addEventListener("click", closeAllSelect);
    </script>
```

Html code:-

```
    <div class="selectBox " >
                                       <div class="input-group mb-2">
                                           <div class="new-select-box d-flex">
                                                   <div class="custom-select-new" id="db"  style="width:400px;">
                                                       <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Operation</label>
   <select name="test" onchange="javascript:setTimeout(&#39;__doPostBack(\&#39;test\&#39;,\&#39;\&#39;)&#39;, 0)" id="test" style="font-family:Calibri;">
       <option selected="selected" value="">Select value...</option>
       <option value="A">A</option>
       <option value="b">b</option>
       <option value="c">c</option>
   </select>
```

Comment: This script will run when it encountered - it will only work if the `<script>` element is at the very bottom of the document or if it's moved into a `function` that's executed with `defer` or after the `DOMContentLoaded` event.

Comment: Also, we can't help you at all unless you post your **rendered** HTML (*not* your `.aspx` or `.cshtml` source). Are you sure your `<select>` elements have `class="custom-select"` set, for example?

Comment: The script you've posted looks like it was written in the mid-2000s because it's using `getElementsByClassName` and `getElementsByTagName` instead of the more modern `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll`. I suspect that you didn't write this script at all and instead copied it verbatim from another website. If you were to actually read through the script then perhaps you'll understand why it doesn't work. Where's your sense of curiosity?

Comment: Here is the html render code.